# Daisy Chain two Dell monitors using USB-C to Displayport - MacBook Pro 2017

Tags: mac, display, multiple-monitors, usb-c, daisychaining

Is it possible to Daisy Chain two Dell u2715h monitors connected to a MacBook Pro 2017?

So the setup would be USB-C to DP cable from the MacBook to first monitor and then the first monitor connected to the second monitor - known as Daisy Chaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested the exact setup on a MacBook Pro 2017 with Sierra and, after an update, also High Sierra.

It did not work. The two monitors will mirror each other and not extend the display.

I don't know why it does not work -
 Apple says, that the following MacBook Pro's support MST (Multi-Stream-Transport). [Taken from this official apple documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206587)

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013) and later
- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015) and later

I have read other places that other users have the same problem. I am guessing it is a software/driver problem as it works with a windows pc and other users have reported that [it works on a mac running windows](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/189542/mbpr-2015-2-5ghz-i7-daisychaining-2-dell-u2414h-61-screens).

Comment: FYI, we have had reports of the same behavior for Dell U2414H monitors and Dell U2515Hs — when daisy-chained, Windows treats them as an extended monitor, but macOS just mirrors one display.

Comment: After reading that official Apple documentation about four times I think the support for MST it's referring to is 5K monitors that require MST in order to support the single monitor off a single cable. There's no mention on the page about daisy chaining.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the 2017 Macbook Pros when used in conjunction with the OWC Thunderbolt 3 dock worked for me. I connected two BenQ monitors with that dock and got the two monitors plus the MBPs screen to come up as separate entities. No work required. Used a Display Port to Thunderbolt (USB-c) cable and a Display Port to mini-Display Port cable. The thunderbolt connector and mini-DP connector were both plugged into the Thunderbolt 3 dock and the dock was plugged into one port on the MBP.

Comment: Someone anonymously added "This solution is only applicable to connecting multiple displays via separate discrete ports, but not in relation to daisy chaining monitors via display port and the multi-stream transport capabilities of the MacBook Pro." to the post.  This should have been a comment and I've voted to reject edit.

Answer (score -1):

It may be possible. Configure as MBP --> DP1.2 --> DP. You must turn DP1.2 off at the 2nd display. Otherwise, the 2nd will mirror the first.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I tried that. I tested the setup and followed the exact configuration you mention - as given by Dell. It even works from a windows computer, but changing only the cable from windows machine to MBP, it does not work. I really cannot believe why people are not more upset about this.

Comment: I confirm that configuration does not work with MBP 15'2018

Comment: this setup doesn't work on MacOS, since they don't support a full-fledged daisy chaining (MST) over DisplayPort. I confirmed on my MBP15"2018 after a week of bying different cables, dongles, and HyperDrive adapter.